# Value changes on clicking tab in html form

Tags: php, jquery, html

> Blockquote

I have a form that has three fields, two text field and one select field. If i enter the price in one text field and select one discount value from dropdown means, the sale price should automatically displayed in the text field. Price calculation is in change function of jquery. Suppose if the sale price has some decimal value, on clicking tab on select box, the decimal point is replaced by 0 in the sale price vale. I dont know why it is happening. Can anyone please help me?

> Blockquote

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Price<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/,'');" maxlength="10"/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Discount</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <select name="discount" class="form-control" id="discount">
                                <option value="0">-- Select Discount Range --</option>
                                <?php
                                $i=5;
                                while($i<=75){ 
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i."%"; ?></option>

                                <?php $i=$i+5; } ?>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sale Price</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sale" name="sale_price" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/,'');" maxlength="10" readonly>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

And my jquery is

```
$('#discount').change(function(){
            var price = $('#price').val();
            var disc = $(this).val();
            var sale = (parseInt(price)-(parseInt(price) * (parseInt(disc) / 100) ));
            $('#sale').val(sale);
        });
```

Comment: can you show to us your code plz? You can use [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to di it

Comment: I have edited my post with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the fonction [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) instead of **ParseInt()**. An Int is an integer which cannot got decimal value.

```
2.53 (Float value)
5 (Int value)
-8 (Int value)
-5.98 (Float value)
```

When you did this

```
 var sale = (parseInt(price)-(parseInt(price) * (parseInt(disc) / 100) ));
```

example: *price equals to 2.50*

> parseInt(2.5) -> Will give 0
>
> 0 - 0 * 10 / 100 = 0

**EDIT:**

I get it, in This line

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/,'');
```

You doesn't allow **.** or **,** character.

Comment: No parseFloat also gives the same result.

Comment: Ok, try to put some console.log during the .change event. Print all values at each line and give a me a callback

Comment: Actually I'm getting the sale price right. If the sale price has decimal point and I click tan on discount select box, the decimal point is replaced by zero